# Wordpress Backend query with vars

Tags: mysql, wordpress, backend

I am getting the postID and successfully dumping it with the following value:
"string(18) "526"". When i put the var $postid in my query it does not give the same result. Code:

```
$postid = $post->ID;
$pdf = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT $wpdb->posts.guid FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_parent = $postid");
```

Any ideas why this occurs?

Greetings and a happy new year

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
global $post;
global $wpdb;
$postid = $post->ID;
$query = $wpdb->prepare('SELECT $wpdb->posts.guid FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_parent = '$postid'');
$pdf = $wpdb->get_results($query);
```

Hope that works.

Comment: Sadly enough it still gives a empty result :(

Comment: i have used similar code as my current answer in one of my own plugin and it worked without issues.. Not sure why it is not working for you. (please try updated answer it should work).

Answer (score 0):

```
$text ="SELECT $wpdb->posts.guid FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_parent = %d";
$query = $wpdb->prepare($text, $postid);
$pdf = $wpdb->get_results($query);
```

It should work with this synthax.